# 2047 Security sandbox violation errors while loading an external swf file into flex from server side

Tags: apache-flex, sandbox

This is my code and i want to place an external swf file for my flex application website.
This is my code:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.my site.com");
loader.load(url);
addChild(loader);
```

If somebody have any help please it will be thankful.
Atishay

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking or what your problem is.  It is not possible for a SWF to access content from another domain unless that other domain gives permission.  To do that you'll have create a crossdomain.xml file.  Here are some good links about cross domain files:

http://www.cflex.net/showfiledetails.cfm?ChannelID=1&Object=addfile&objectID=287

And here is the crossdomain.xml file I use for The Flex Show Web site:

http://www.theflexshow.com/crossdomain.xml

```
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
 <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This allows any Flash SWF to access content on theflexshow.com domain.

If this doesn't help address the issue, you're going to have to tell us exactly what your problem is.

Comment: @Flex SDK If it solves your issue it is customary to mark it as the answe and/or give the answer an upvote.